# Using Grouping to Limit the Scope of a \newtheorem in the Combine Document Class

Tags: theorems, combine

I am combining a set of articles using the `combine` document class. However, use of the `\newtheorem` command in the individual articles causes an error, when these environments have already been defined by an earlier paper. I would like to maintain the ability to compile each file individually, which precludes simply deleting or commenting out these `\newtheorem` commands. The `combine` class seems preferable to the `standalone` class, which apparently simply ignores the entire preamble; this would eliminate the title and author information from each paper, as well as any `\newcommands` each author may have defined.

For example, a main file:

```
\documentclass{combine}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{papers}

\coltoctitle{An article} \coltocauthor{A.~N.~Author} \label{art1} \import{ThmTest}

\coltoctitle{Another article} \coltocauthor{A.~N.~Author} \label{art2} \import{ThmTest2}

\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

together with the files `ThmTest.tex` and `ThmTest2.tex` (same contents):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\begin{Theorem}
A theorem.
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

The `combine` documentation (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf) suggests on p. 14 that the problem can be avoided by "cunning use of grouping." Simply adding braces around each imported article doesn't seem to fix the problem, so what kind of grouping might work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authors suggest that their solution to the `\newtheorem` problem is that they redefine the `\newtheorem` macros to be local rather than global.  My **guess** is that by loading the `amsthm` package in the preamble, you have overwritten that code.  In any case, removing the package from the preamble, and grouping as they suggest seems to fix the problem.

```
\documentclass{combine}
\begin{document}
\begin{papers}
\coltoctitle{An article} \coltocauthor{A.~N.~Author} \label{art1} \begingroup\import{ThmTest}\endgroup

\coltoctitle{Another article} \coltocauthor{A.~N.~Author} \label{art2} \begingroup\import{ThmTest2}\endgroup
\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Of all the things I tried, simply deleting all the theorem packages never occurred to me!